# Does google bot follow pages labeled as "noindex" "follow"?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Recently I've came across the question that: what happens if you label a page as "noindex" + "follow" ? I know that "noindex" is used to tell the search engine : "I don't want you to index my page" but what happens if you set "follow" instead of "no follow"? Does it have any drawbacks or negative repercusions in ranking?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question first.

Answer (score 0):

If Googlebot crawls a noindex,follow page it will not add the page to the index, but it will add the links on it to its "to crawl" list. So links on a noindex page may be discovered that way and crawled later.

It's not a 100% reliable way to get Google to crawl links on a noindex page or to give those linked to pages credit because of the link. Google will over time pay less attention to a noindex page and any information it provides.

Note that you don't need to specify follow, it is the default behaviour.